# Sendgrid, Firebase email not sending in production using Netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, sendgrid, netlify

I'm using Nuxt ,Sendgrid, and Firebase for a simple contact form. Netlify for hosting. My form works great locally, and sends email no problem. When I push the project to Netlify the emails are not getting sent. The email works locally because I am hard coding the Sendgrid API key into the NODEMAILER createTransport function as such:

LOCAL CODE: (works flawless)

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port: 587,
  secure: false, 
  auth: {
    user: 'apikey',
    pass: 'MY API NUMBER IS HERE',
  },
})
```

now when I push the code to Github / Netlify I have the actual api number in my gitignore as I do not want that number exposed. So now it looks like this:

```
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      port: 587,
      secure: false, 
      auth: {
        user: 'apikey',
        pass: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
      },
    })
```

My .env file is in the ROOT of the project that is storing the API key, the sendgrid functions folder is /functions/index.js. I'm wondering if the functions folder cannot access the information in the .env file?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already tried this but have you set environment variables in the deploy tab of Netlify?

[image: Netlify Env Vars]